# Prime ideals of localization of absolutely flat modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, flatness

There is an exercise (chapter 3, Exercise 10, page number 44) in atiyah mc Donald.

> $A$ is absolutely flat iff $A_m$ is a field for each maximal ideal $m$.

I actually proved this statement and it is not hard to do. But my question is where will maximal ideals map to?

We have the following, "There is an one-to-one correspondence between prime ideals of $A_m$ and prime ideals of $A$ not intersecting complement of $m$."

In the light of the above fact, in localization of absolutely flat ring at maximal ideal gives field, which has only two ideals. Now $0$ in $A$ corresponds to $0$ in $A_m$. So, To which ideal in $A_m$, $m$ corresponds to?

This might be some kinda trivial or silly question.  But I was clearly missing something and I couldn't figured it out. Please help.

Added:
Assume $A$ is an integral domain, if necessary.  So that $0$ will be prime.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard

Comment: Unnecessary to add the hypothesis: an absolutely flat integral domain is a field. The ideal $0$ in $A$ maps to $(0)$ in $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$, but the inverse image of $(0)$ in $A$ is $\mathfrak m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an absolutely flat integral domain, then $A$ is a field, this is because absolutely flat rings are zero-dimensional, so every prime ideal is maximal. Thus there will be no $m$ to consider as $0$ is the only prime ideal in $A$.

Comment: And $0$ is prime iff $A$ is integral domain?

Comment: @LordShadow yes

Comment: Oh, Well seems like nothing is missing and I thought "conclusion " as "contradiction ".